Why does the web socket give an error when connecting to the server?
I am trying to connect to a web socket on the server, to which the socket gives an error stating that it was failed to connect
Rust code:
use axum::{
    extract::{ws::WebSocket, WebSocketUpgrade},
    response::IntoResponse,
    routing::get,
    Router,
};
use tokio::net::TcpListener;
use tower_http::services::ServeDir;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("localhost:3000").await.unwrap();
    axum::serve(listener, router()).await.unwrap();
}

fn router() -> Router {
    Router::new()
        .route("/message_list", get(hello_world))
        .nest_service("/", ServeDir::new("static"))
}

async fn hello_world(ws: WebSocketUpgrade) -> impl IntoResponse {
    let _res = ws.on_upgrade(|ws| socet_handler(ws));
}

async fn socet_handler(mut ws: WebSocket) {
    println!("IT READY!");
    let _res = ws.send(axum::extract::ws::Message::Text("hi".to_string()));
}

js code:
let socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3000/message_list")

I also tried to change 'ws' to 'wss' in the URL but it doesnt help.
there is a constant error on the site:

WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/message_list' failed

What could this be related to?

You won't be able to use wss:// without the TLS layer.

A) Are you sure the Rust service is running and accepting connections? Can you confirm with another tool like curl? B) Are these both on the same local machine? Is one of them in a container where localhost is relative to that?

yes, the rust service is running and accepts connections, the "soket_handler" function has a command that sends a message when connected, and it is triggered correctly every time it is started. both of them are on the same local machine

Your socet_handler doesn't keep the websocket connection alive, it sends a message and then immediately ends the function - dropping the websocket.
Try adding a loop listening for messages like in the documentation:
async fn socet_handler(mut socket: WebSocket) {
    println!("IT READY!");
    let _res = ws.send(axum::extract::ws::Message::Text("hi".to_string())).await;

    while let Some(msg) = socket.recv().await {
        // handle the message
    }
}

Your code also discards the response created from on_upgrade and returns an empty (()) response instead. Remove the let _res =  part and let it return like this:
async fn hello_world(ws: WebSocketUpgrade) -> impl IntoResponse {
    ws.on_upgrade(|ws| socet_handler(ws))
}

You also were not .await-ing the send call, which means it wouldn't actually send.
